# powershell get handle on new window

Tags: powershell

We are trying to use Powershell to automate some testing on our site.
We have hit a problem when we issue the click event on an anchor which opens a new tab.
We need to get a handle on the new tab and then continue processing by clicking the print button on the new tab. 
How could this be done using Powershell?

```
set-executionpolicy remotesigned
$ie = new-object -com "InternetExplorer.Application"
$ie.navigate("xxxxx.com")
$ie.visible = $true
$doc = $ie.document
While ($ie.Busy) {Sleep 10}
$doc -eq $null
$tb1 = $doc.getElementByID("username")
$tb2 = $doc.getElementByID("password")
$tb1.value = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$tb2.value = "xxxxxxxxxxx"
$btn =  $ie.document.getelementsbytagname("input")|where{$_.name -eq "Submit"} 
$btn.click()
$ie.navigate("xxxxx.com/admin/reports.html#")
$link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('A') | where-object {$_.innerText -eq 'All Photos'}
$link.click()

<<<<<<<<<<< it's here where a new tab is open and we need to get a handle on the new page to be able to click the print button >>>>>>>>>>>

$popupHandle = $ie.openwindow.winrefs[$targetName]
$btn =  $popupHandle.document.getelementsbytagname("input")|where{$_.name -eq "print"}
$btn.click()
```

We are new to Powershell so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks
Richard

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Not easy to answer your question without seeing your code. However, you can probably find some tracks here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163301.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Try opening your new tab using **$ie.navigate2** and **0x0800** to put it in a new foreground tab. That will automatically focus you on the new tab allowing you to grab the print button.

e.g.

```
# Setting page to new foreground tab here
$newTabPage = $ie.navigate2("www.xxxx.com",0x0800)
```

Similarly, you can use **0x1000** to open the page in a new background tab, which will open the new tab but not automatically bring it to focus.

```
# Setting page to new background tab here
$newTabPage = $ie.navigate2("www.xxxx.com",0x1000)
```